# ESXI 10g Network but Win-2008-R2 limited with 1G speed

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-esxi

We recently upgraded all of our vmware esxi 6.5/6.7 servers networks on 10G.

[image: esxi 10g network]

All the guests which have windows 2012 or above can transfer data above 1G as shown in below pic.

[image: 10G-trasnfer-on-2012-orabove-guests]

but on same physical server, all Windows 2008 R2 (64bit with vmware tools installed) related guests vm are limited to 1Gb transfer only as shown in below pic

[image: 2008r2 limited to 1g transfer]

[image: 10g on 2008r2]

In 2008R2 guests, I tried to added same Network adapter settings that are on 2012/2016 guests, but no avail. I added different network adapter in w2008r2 vm guest, like VMXNET3 (which shows 10Gb connectivity), VMXNET2 enhanced, and others, but still all 2008R2 guests are not transferring above 1G.

When I perform above testing, I made sure that there should be no other tasks running that can utilize network/disks. So the Vm guests stays idle from network/disk point of view for test purposes.

Is there any tuning that is required ni 2008R2 so that i can utilize 10G bandwidth?

Comment: Remember that 2008R2 has been out of support for a year now. Whatever is on those VMs should have been updated or decommissioned _years_ ago. It's possible that there is no solution to this other than to finally do the long overdue upgrade.

Comment: * I am testing single 5 GB ISO file which is available inside shared folder on 2012 VM guest.

* From 2012 vm guest to other 2012 vm guests , speed is OK (that is above 2 GB, as shown in image)

* from 2012 to 2008 ot 2008 to 2012, transfer speed is limited under 1 GB

* there is no AV/FW enabled on all guests

* Testing is not done simultaneously on all vm guests, it is done one by one either (when all other vm guests are idle by network/disk pov) on 2012 to 2012, 2012 to 2008